Can i run parallel test execution of a same set of tests with different set of data like browser, env, username, password
My intention here is to run the tests in parallel with 2 sets of data. I am using selenium-java-bdd-cucumber. I have 10 .feature files, want to run in 2 environments like Stage and QA, so total of 20 tests, want to execute in parallel with 5 threads.
I tried with adding corresponding parameters in testng_qa.xml and testng_stage.xml, then finally added these two suites in testng_master.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false" thread-count="5" verbose="2">
  <suite-files>
     <suite-file path="testng_qa.xml"/>
  </suite-files>
 <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="testng_stage.xml"/>
 </suite-files>
</suite>

Then running from commandline with
mvn clean test -Dname=value -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=TestNG.xml


Hello Subbarao, and the question is...?

@MarcePuente it is not working for me with the above approach. Do we have any other ways or workarounds to do it. Thanks!
